# Show ellipsis with sort indicator

Tags: html, css

[In my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eAC8G/6/) I have three examples of how to show a sort indicator on a table header.

[image: Un-collapsed headers]

My issue is on the third column. When I shrink to ellipsis, the sort indicator is hidden in Chrome and in IE it is placed on top of the text.

**Chrome**

[image: Collapsed CHROME]

**IE**

[image]

Is there a way to have the sort indicator **stay snug with the caption** and **stay visible** when displaying the ellipsis (Similar to the second column)?

I've tried breaking the indicator out into its own span, but I can't seem to get the span with the caption to collapse.

Comment: Have you considered using this at all: http://quocity.com/colresizable/ ?

Comment: @AlexW - I've seen this kind of thing before, but at this time column re-sizing is not a requirement. Thanks for the link though, this may prove useful for future projects.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this seems more noticeable in IE than Chrome. One way around this might be to use the the CSS `content` property and move the sort indicator into that and remove the background-image from the .indicator-right class.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/eAC8G/7/)**

CSS

```
.indicator-right:after {
    content:url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFQAJAIAAACMtMP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAAVAAkAAAIXjI+AywnaYnhUMoqt3gZXPmVg94yJVQAAOw==);
}
```

Comment: Very interesting, I'll definitely play with this idea! However, if possible, I would like the indicator to stay visible when collapsed (when the ellipsis are shown). If anything though, this seems to standardize the behavior between the browsers.